# apply css to a td element that has no class

Tags: css, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I have a table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="twelve columns" style="width:600px;margin: 0 20px;">
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                          ' . $issue_body . '
                        </td>
```

With no class for TR or TD. I am using some custom module for Drupal, and trying to send email via PHPMailer.(for Newsletter and Subscriptions)

Email looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEHnb.jpg

I'd like to move text to the right side of the image.

If I add `style="background-color:red";` into TR or TD background gets red, but how do I make this text float. 
I have tried adding `float:left;` but didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Ah,so you are one of those who send those emails!

Comment: its a subscription/newsletter email

Comment: Should the text be floating right (so fill the whole line when the image end) or just be on the column on the right?

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin well yea, should be on the right side of the image, and fill the whole line when image end.

Comment: you can't use floats within emails... If you need a different layout of the table then you'll have to manually change it. Of it won't be consistent across clients

Comment: @Aaron well I used floating in some cases above, and it worked. Any suggestion how to move this one ?

Comment: Read up on CSS use in email... you really can't use floats https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @Aaron ok Thanks. Can we pretend that this is not about email, what would be a solution? :)

Comment: with table cells?? you're fighting an uphill battle.

Comment: @Aaron what about vertical or horizontal align? tried with floats but no luck.

Comment: how exactly did you try adding "float:left"?

Comment: @andi <td style="float:left;"> for example.

Comment: well, you don't want to float the td, you want to float the image, right?  The the text will wrap around it.

Comment: @andi yes. but td wont accept any css. it has to be done within the tag. i think...i have tried adding a class like `<td class="test">` and later in `<head>` using style and adding some css, but didn't work.

Comment: have you tried just adding an inline style to the image tag, like `<img src="..." style="float:left;" />` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Image in the same container of the text, **just ensure to set the image to behave as an inline element**.

```
img{
  display: inline;
}
```

or just print it out as an attribute:

```
<img style="display: inline;" src="..."/>
```

It will make your image not to use all the block width space, and get arranged along with any text element such as p, span, strong, em...

Otherwise, you will need to rethink the layout you are using.